# 'Late' handling of unhandled exceptions c#

Tags: c#, .net, mef, maf

I have used MEF in my project to provide extensibility for plugins. This works great, but I have since realised the need to isolate the plugin assemblies from the main app, so at the very least, the main app doesn't crash if a plugin does.

Unfortunately, this seems to be more complex than anticipated - requiring a combination of MAF and MEF to offer the best solution.

But, I am low on resources and time, so for the time being at least, a satisfactory work-around would suffice.

I am already using the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event for detailed logging purposes; I noticed with this I can also detect which `AppDomain` caused the exception. Is there a way I can actually handle these unhandled exceptions at this point?This way I could conditionally check if the exceptions occurred in external assemblies, and if so, ignore them so the main app continues unaffected.

OFC, any alternative approaches suggested will be appreciated too.

Comment: There is an event named assemblyloaded in THE appdomain. I would try that onde also

Comment: I know mef but What is MAF?

Comment: @LuisFilipe Sounds interesting; any example code to illustrate? And RE: MAF/MEF... they are two annoyingly similarly named frameworks. If I had more time, this looks like what I should do: http://kentb.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/maf-and-mef.html

Comment: Sorry no code now. I AM at my cell phone

Comment: @LuisFilipe ok, I will look in to it. BTW, would that event also detect a plugin crash which occurred after its initial loading? In my context, plugins are loaded at startup but may be activated or 'fully' executed after the main app is loaded. Crashes in these plugins could in theory occur at any time.